# How to link to "unix-java" from Java in 2019

Tags: java, dbus, networkmanager

I am using the NetworkManager / DBus code from [here](https://github.com/Garikk/kk-dbus-nm-java).  It builds successfully but at runtime produces:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no unix-java in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2660)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:829)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1870)
    at cx.ath.matthew.unix.UnixSocket.<clinit>(UnixSocket.java:40)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.Transport.connect(Transport.java:772)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.Transport.<init>(Transport.java:737)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusConnection.<init>(DBusConnection.java:299)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusConnection.getConnection(DBusConnection.java:282)
```

This is a Maven project.  Can I fix this problem by pulling in another artifact or declaration?  I've been going round in circles all day looking at stuff that's 10+ years old trying to work out if I'm using obsolete code because previously I'd been using my own classes generated via introspection but now apparently I need this extra library.

Or is the answer that this unix-java library is something I have to pull in via my distro's package manager?  be it `emerge`, `apt-get` or whichever.

Comment: first Check dependency scope, then check if it exists in `.m2`. If not download same version and paste with relative path.

Comment: Same version of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for their suggestions.  What I eventually did was use [this](https://github.com/hypfvieh/dbus-java) DBus stuff with [this](https://github.com/michaelNGV/kk-dbus-nm-java) NetworkManager stuff.  Obviously I had to change a lot of the `import` package names in *kk-dbus-nm-java* but the benefit is that hypfvieh's DBus stuff doesn't need a separate socket library.

Answer (score 2):

Found [this DBus service page](https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli/wiki/DBus-service) which may be unrelated, but mentions the same native library you are trying to use:

> For dbus support you need jni/unix-java.so installed on your system (Debian: libunixsocket-java ArchLinux: libmatthew-unix-java (AUR)).

It mentions `unix-java.so` as the native library, the same one you are trying to load, so if you are on Debian/Ubuntu, try doing:

```
apt install libunixsocket-java
```

Comment: Also just noticed that page has `libmatthew-unix-java` for Arch, and given that there's also a mention of `cx.ath.matthew.unix.UnixSocket` in your stack trace, might be a pretty good chance they are the same thing.

Comment: how to install this on a mac?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some underlying code is using java native interface (JNI) and requires unix shared object be loaded.

This is typically achieved by adding the .so file to the library path, while launching the JVM.

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/the/directory/containing/so

This can also be achieved by adding the library via -Djava.library.path  JVM args.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to a different DBus project that had similar requirements. This project had these dependencies:

1. `libdbus-java-2.7.jar` (the project already contained this jar)
2. `/usr/share/java/unix.jar` (was satisfied by installing debian package and adding jar from it)
3. `/usr/share/java/hexdump.jar` (satisfied through maven)

I executed the following in a Linux shell.

```
sudo apt install libunixsocket-java
```

I was using Eclipse to configure and run this project, so the following applies to Eclipse.

I converted the project to maven project. Then I added the following maven dependencies.

```html
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.abstractj.libmatthew/hexdump -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.abstractj.libmatthew</groupId>
    <artifactId>hexdump</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I include `/usr/share/java/unix.jar` to the Java BuildPath->Libraries.
Then included the `/usr/lib/jni` path at "Java BuildPath->Libraries->unix.jar->Native Library Location"

Finally: hit run.